# Determine if the solution to a division is odd or even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Is there a way to quickly determine if the solution to a division operation will be odd or even? I need a quick way determine that in a program. Doing a complete a complete division takes up too much time.

Here is something that is known beforehand:

- both numbers are even
- there is no remainder
- in $a/b$, b is not $2^n$

I tried to look into patterns in their binary representations to no avail. Currently what I have is

```
isOdd = (a / b) & 1;  //pseudocode
```

but dividing two big numbers is just too expensive.

Comment: Are they machine integers or an arbitrary precision type?

Comment: @DanielFischer They are integers (of type `unsigned int`.)

Comment: And you want things efficient as hell? The best is then almost certainly the `ctz` instruction (`count of trailing zeros`), might be named differently on different processors, and how to get it would depend on the compiler, something like `__builtin_ctzl` on gcc, might also work with clang. Without the machine instruction, I think `(a ^ (a-1)) == (b ^ (b-1))` would be the fastest, two subtractions, two xors, one comparison to tell you whether the quotient is odd.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I will give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the numbers in binary form already?  Then just compute $ord_2$ of $a$ and $b$.  Here, $ord_2(n)$ denotes the greatest power of $2$ which divides $n$.  Thus $ord_2(5)=0$, $ord_2(24)=3$, and so on.  You can read this off from the binary forms...$ord_2(n)$ is the number of zeros before the first one in the binary representation (reading from right to left).  Thus $$ord_2(10111011000)=3$$
To solve your problem, note that the quotient $\frac ab$ will be even if and only if $ord_2(a)>ord_2(b)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but determining the exact number of zeros might be slower than just a simple division operation. Is there's some fast way to determine that that I happen to not know?

Comment: Well, you don't need the exact number.  All you need is to know if the two counts match or not.  Just make a loop wherein you strike off a zero from the right so long as both terms have a zero there.  Once $b$'s zeros are done, just check to see if the units place of $a$ is $0$ or not.

Comment: Side note:  I passed this question on to my brother, who does this sort of thing for a living.  He (instantly) replied:  "rightmostAbit = A ^ (A & (A - 1));  /* that's an XOR in addition to the & and the subtraction */
rightmostBbit = B ^ (B & (B - 1)); 
if (rightmostAbit > rightmostBbit)
    then A/B is even, if integer (this was promised)"  Not entirely sure I follow, but perhaps you do.

Answer (score 1):

C-style code:

```
/* Assumes b!=0 and a divisible by b */
bit_index = 1
while (b&bit_index==0) {
  if (a & bit_index) { /* Error, a is not divisible by b; odd over even */ }
  bit_index = bit_index >> 1
}
return (a&bit_index)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

if a is even then a = $2^n*a'$ for some odd a'.   b is even so b = $2^m*b'$.  So a/b = $2^{n-m}(a/b)$  which is even if n > m but odd if n = m.